# My Website responding properly on chrome browser in desktop and not on Edge and also not working on Mobile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, amazon-route53

My 
In cloudfront I have selected behaviour as HTTPS only with get,head,put,post,delete methods.
In my Backend,which is hosted on Elastic Bean Stalk i have placed a load balancer which acccepts only https requests and attached my website ssl certificate with it.
In my chrome Browser in desktop,It responds correctly but in Edge it shows:

Http failure response for https://aspertime-env.mzwstbdszd.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/employee/login: 0 Unknown Error

Can Anyone help me to solve this Problem?

It doesn't work on mobile also

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is very clear if you click on the link as SSL has created against

https://aspertime.xyz/

not against

https://aspertime-env.mzwstbdszd.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/employee/login.
[image]

So the certificate is created against some other DNS name, so when you call for frontend it will not able to communicate with the backend because of Certificate Error.

To solve this you need to update your DNS record for backend if the are running on two different platforms so follow these steps.

- create a subdomain for backend too, https://backend.aspertime.xyz/
- update your DNS record and add  `backend.aspertime.xyz` this which should point to your Load balancer
- verify the call from browser this https://backend.aspertime.xyz/employee/login
- If the above step work updates your frontend app to use https://backend.aspertime.xyz/employee/login this endpoint to communicate with backend.